# How to set limit of Button in tkinter so that its only execute once?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on a simple tkinter based GUI program that print "DONE"
When Button is clicked but the problem is when i click on button again and again its print "DONE" again and again so i want to limit it to once..

```
from tkinter import *

def b1_action():
    Label_1 = Label(text = "DONE")
    Label_1.pack()

top = Tk()
top.geometry("500x500")

b1 = Button(text = "CLICK ME",command = b1_action)`enter code here`
b1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

I expect that "DONE" print only once but its print again and again as i press CLICK ME Button..

Comment: You can disable the button by `b1.config(state="disabled")`

Answer (score 1):

The line of code you're looking for is

```
b1.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

Given that you stated your command as b1_action in your b1 declaration, that function should look something like this.

```
def b1_action(): 
    Label_1 = Label(text = "DONE")
    Label_1.pack()
    b1.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two way for do that.

The first option that you have is to disable the button right after that you clicked it,

```py
from tkinter import *


def b1_action():
    Label_1 = Label(text="DONE")
    Label_1.pack()
    b1.configure(state=DISABLED)


top = Tk()
top.geometry("500x500")

b1 = Button(text="CLICK ME", command=b1_action)
b1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

The second option is that you create a variable that check if the button has ever been pressed or not

```py
from tkinter import *

BUTTON_PRESSED = False

def b1_action():
    global BUTTON_PRESSED

    if not BUTTON_PRESSED:
        Label_1 = Label(text="DONE")
        Label_1.pack()
        BUTTON_PRESSED = True


top = Tk()
top.geometry("500x500")

b1 = Button(text="CLICK ME", command=b1_action)
b1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

But i advice to use the first option, it's simpler and more efficient